# SQLDeveloper set default linesize

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

As per title, how to set Oracle SQL Developer default linesize so that I don't have to set it every time I open the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an SQL file with the content that sets the desired linesize, e.g:

**login.sql**

```
set linesize 200
```

Then in SQL Developer, go to `Tools/Preferences/Database`, and set this file at `Filename for connection startup script`.