# sqlplus SP2-0341 (line overflow during variable substitution)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, sqlplus

I want to export an Oracle database to a file and i'm using SQLDeveloper on Windows for that (the resulting SQL text file is about 35MB). This results in very long lines.

I hit a snag when importing the file using sqlplus on linux:

```
SP2-0341: line overflow during variable substitution (>3000 characters at line 1)
```

This occurs on multiple lines.

I see no options on how to limit the length of the lines when exporting. I've tried to [set line size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106169/sqldeveloper-set-default-linesize) and then export, to no avail. I've also tried to [edit](https://superuser.com/questions/895755/how-to-break-long-lines-in-vim#895836) the file but the vim tools i used focus on explicit line length and not the semantics of SQL (they'll break strings). Also my regex-fu can only go as far as surrounding the `VALUES` keyword with newlines, but even then the lines are still much longer than 3000. Also, 35MB is a lot to edit by hand.

I'm limited to those tools and RDBMS but i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: why do you want to export the database? If you want to transport it to another Oracle database then use expdp or exp, depending on the Oracle version.

Comment: @miracle173 I don't remember anymore, I believe it was because of different Oracle RDBMS and tools versions, as well as different OS and compatibility issues. Anyway, it's been solved.

Comment: I see now this is an old question. It caught my attention because you made an edit 4 hours ago so it was diplayed as actibe question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL*Plus is not a data loading tool. Use the proper tools.

SQL Developer can create CSV files.
Instead of `SQL*Plus`, use `SQL*Loader` to load the data.

[SQL*Plus Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/SQL-Plus-limits.html#GUID-93CA1BD6-888F-40FD-B57F-0B782C96854F)

[image]

Comment: Well pontied out, thanks, but the complexity of the control file(s) versus just loading `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements just baffles me. It seems almost like each and every Oracle-related tool is intentionally over-engineered and bloated.

Answer (score 2):

The 3000-character limit is for any single line in the SQL.  Add line breaks to reduce the maximum line length.

Instead of

```
select columna, columnb, columnc ........ from table
```

do this

```
select
columna,
columnb,
columnc
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html). I had the same issue with sqlplus and switching to SQLcl helped.